# Error when running Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I configure apache spark --one master node and two worker node
I running this jar file and dataset following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class dmlab.main.MainDriver --master local[2] PAMAE-Spark.jar USCensus1990.csv 10 4000 5 4 1
```

This is successfully in job 3. but, error in job 4 is starting. [image]

Please kindly help me.

```
package dmlab.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD;
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;
import dmlab.main.Algorithms;
import dmlab.main.FloatPoint;
import dmlab.main.PAMAE;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.Tuple2;
public final class PAMAE {
public static String eleDivider = ",";
public static JavaRDD<FloatPoint> readFile(JavaSparkContext sc, String 
inputPath, int numOfCores)
{
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(inputPath,numOfCores);
    JavaRDD<FloatPoint> dataSet = lines.map(new 
PAMAE.ParsePoint()).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
    return dataSet;
}

public static List<FloatPoint> PHASE_I(JavaSparkContext sc, 
JavaRDD<FloatPoint> dataSet, int numOfClusters, int numOfSampledObjects, int 
numOfSamples, int numOfCores)
{   
    List<FloatPoint> samples = dataSet.takeSample(true, 
numOfSampledObjects*numOfClusters*10);
    JavaRDD<FloatPoint> sampleSet = sc.parallelize(samples);

    List<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> candidateSet = 
sampleSet.mapToPair(new PAMAE.Sampling(numOfClusters))

.groupByKey().mapValues(new PAMAE.PAM(numOfSampledObjects, numOfClusters))
                                                        .collect();

   JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> candidateSetRDD = 
sc.parallelize(candidateSet).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
    List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> costList = cluteringError(sc, dataSet, 
candidateSetRDD);       

    List<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> candidateList = 
candidateSetRDD.collect();
    int finalKey = -1;
    double phaseIError = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<costList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(phaseIError > costList.get(i)._2())
        {
            phaseIError = costList.get(i)._2();
            finalKey = costList.get(i)._1();
        }
    } 
    List<FloatPoint> bestSeed = null;
    for(int i=0; i<candidateList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(candidateList.get(i)._1() == finalKey)
            bestSeed = candidateList.get(i)._2();
    }

    System.out.println("PHASE I CLUSTERING ERROR : " + phaseIError+"\n");

    candidateSetRDD.unpersist();

    return bestSeed;
}
public static List<FloatPoint> PHASE_II(JavaSparkContext sc, 
JavaRDD<FloatPoint> dataSet, List<FloatPoint> bestSeed, int numOfClusters, 
int numOfSampledObjects, int numOfSamples, int numOfCores)
{
   JavaRDD<FloatPoint> bestSeedRDD = sc.parallelize(bestSeed);
    bestSeedRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
    List<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> temp = dataSet.mapToPair(new 
 PAMAE.AssignPoint(numOfCores))

.groupByKey().mapValues(new PAMAE.ModifiedWeiszfeld(bestSeedRDD)).collect();

     ArrayList<FloatPoint> finalMedoids = new ArrayList<FloatPoint>();

     for(int i=0; i<numOfClusters; i++)
     {
         int index = -1;
         double minCost = Double.MAX_VALUE;
         for(int j=0; j<numOfCores; j++)
         {
             if(minCost > temp.get(j)._2().get(i).getCost())
             {  index = j;
                 minCost = temp.get(j)._2().get(i).getCost();}
         }
         finalMedoids.add(temp.get(index)._2().get(i));
         temp.get(index)._2().get(i).toString());

     }
    bestSeedRDD.unpersist();
    return finalMedoids;
}

public static List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> cluteringError(JavaSparkContext 
sc, JavaRDD<FloatPoint> dataSet, JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> 
medoids)
{
     List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> Error = dataSet.flatMapToPair(new 
PAMAE.CostCaculator(medoids)).
                                                            reduceByKey(new 
Function2<Double, Double, Double>() {

call(Double x, Double y) throws Exception {

                                                            return x+y;
                                                            }
                                                            }).collect(); 
    return Error;
}


public static double FinalError(JavaSparkContext sc, JavaRDD<FloatPoint> 
dataSet, List<FloatPoint> finalMedoids)
{
    Tuple2<Integer,List<FloatPoint>> medoids = new Tuple2<Integer, 
List<FloatPoint>>(1,finalMedoids);
    List<Tuple2<Integer,List<FloatPoint>>> temp = new 
ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer,List<FloatPoint>>>();
    temp.add(medoids);  
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> finalSetRDD = 
sc.parallelize(temp).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());   
    List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> finalError =  cluteringError(sc, dataSet, 
finalSetRDD);

    return finalError.get(0)._2;
}


public static class ParsePoint implements Function<String, FloatPoint> {

    @Override
    public FloatPoint call(String line) {
        String[] toks = line.toString().split(eleDivider);
        FloatPoint pt = new FloatPoint(toks.length,-1);
        for(int j=0; j<toks.length; j++)
            pt.getValues()[j] = (Float.parseFloat(toks[j]));
        return pt;
    }
}


public static class Sampling implements PairFunction<FloatPoint, Integer, 
FloatPoint> {
    private int parallel = 0;

    public Sampling(int parallel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.parallel = parallel;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<Integer, FloatPoint> call(FloatPoint value) throws 
  Exception {
    int key = (int)(Math.random()*parallel);
    value.setKey(key);
    return new Tuple2(key,value);
    }
}


public static class PAM implements Function<Iterable<FloatPoint>, 
List<FloatPoint>>{
    private int sampleNumber = 0;
    private int K = 0;

    public PAM( int sampleNumber, int K) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.sampleNumber = sampleNumber;
        this.K = K;
    }

    @Override
    public List<FloatPoint> call(Iterable<FloatPoint> values) throws 
  Exception {

        List<FloatPoint> sampledDataSet = new ArrayList<FloatPoint>();
        for(FloatPoint pt : values)
            sampledDataSet.add(pt);

        HashSet<Integer> sampleIndex = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int dataSize = sampledDataSet.size();
        while(sampleIndex.size() != sampleNumber)
            sampleIndex.add((int)(Math.random()*dataSize));

        List<FloatPoint> samplePoints = new ArrayList<FloatPoint>();
        for(Integer sample : sampleIndex)
            samplePoints.add(sampledDataSet.get(sample));
        sampledDataSet.clear();

        float[][] preCalcResult = Algorithms.PreCalculate(samplePoints);

        List<FloatPoint> sampleInit = 
 Algorithms.chooseInitialMedoids(samplePoints, K, preCalcResult, 0.5f);     

        Algorithms.PAM(samplePoints, sampleInit, preCalcResult);

        return sampleInit;
    }
}


public static class CostCaculator implements PairFlatMapFunction<FloatPoint, 
Integer, Double>{
    List<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> Candidates;

    public CostCaculator(JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, List<FloatPoint>>> 
 candidateSetRDD) {


        Candidates = candidateSetRDD.collect();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> call(FloatPoint pt)
            throws Exception {

        List<Tuple2<Integer, Double>> output = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, 
 Double>>();

        for(int i=0; i<Candidates.size(); i++)
        {
            int key = Candidates.get(i)._1();
            List<FloatPoint> pts = Candidates.get(i)._2();

            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for(int j=0; j<pts.size(); j++)
            {
                double newCost = FunctionSet.distance(pt, pts.get(j));
                if(min > newCost)
                    min = newCost;
            }   
            output.add(new Tuple2<Integer, Double>(key, min));
        }
        return output;
    }
}


public static class AssignPoint implements PairFunction<FloatPoint, Integer, 
FloatPoint> {
    private int coreNum=-1;

    public AssignPoint(int coreNum) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.coreNum = coreNum;
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<Integer, FloatPoint> call(FloatPoint value) throws 
Exception {
    int key = (int)(Math.random()*coreNum);
    value.setKey(key);
    return new Tuple2(key,value);
    }
}


public static class ModifiedWeiszfeld implements 
 Function<Iterable<FloatPoint>, List<FloatPoint>>{
    private List<FloatPoint> medoids = null;

    public ModifiedWeiszfeld(JavaRDD<FloatPoint> bestSeed) {

        this.medoids = bestSeed.collect();
    }

    @Override
    public List<FloatPoint> call(Iterable<FloatPoint> values) throws 
Exception {


        List<FloatPoint> localDataSet = new ArrayList<FloatPoint>();    
        for(FloatPoint pt : values)
            localDataSet.add(pt);
        for(FloatPoint pt: medoids)
            localDataSet.add(pt);   
        List<FloatPoint> finalMedoid = null;
        finalMedoid = Algorithms.refinement(localDataSet, medoids, 0.01);

        return finalMedoid; 
}
```

}
}
i run this source code. this work has finished job 3. but , job 4 is starting .error is occuring.

Comment: Please provide Spark version and sample of your code at dmlab.main.PAMAE.

Comment: that seems like a version mismatch error. Either, java, scala or spark. You ought checking those out

Comment: I use spark version 2.0.0 and java version 7